# Azure web app throwing error when syncing with my github repository

Tags: django, azure

In syncing with code I recently pushed to my github repository, my Django Azure Web App throws me the error: 
**pip can't proceed with requirement 'anyjson==0.3.3 (from -r requirements.txt (line 2))' due to a pre-existing build directory.
location: D:\home\site\wwwroot\env\build\anyjson
This is likely due to a previous installation that failed.
pip is being responsible and not assuming it can delete this.
Please delete it and try again.**

How do I manually delete this myself? Like, is there a way I can connect to the Azure Web App via SSH or something? It's not immediately clear what I need to do here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to yoursite.**scm**.azurewebsites.net. 
Login with your Azure credentials.
This will give you a console with various tools, including a file browser you can use to delete the files in question.